# List lambda expression throwing InvalidOperationException for one particular query

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have this snippet.

```
List<Frames> FrameList;
```

where Frames is a class containing only primitives including a string field "ExerciseID".

```
...


void GetFramesForExercise(string exerciseID)

    ....

    if (exerciseID == "3.2.2") { 
       Console.Write(""); }  // quick and dirty to add a breakpoint

    if (FramesList[115].ExerciseID.Equals(exerciseID)) { 
       Console.Write(""); } // quick and dirty to add a breakpoint

    frames = (Frames)FramesList.Single(r => r.ExerciseID.Equals(exerciseID));
```

By putting breakpoints on the console.write statements, I am able to see that exerciseID does indeed equal "3.2.2" and that FramesList[115] points to an instance of Exercise with ID equal to "3.2.2".  The instance pointed to is correctly initiliased.

Why does my query throw an InvalidOperationException?

Comment: Please post full exception message

Comment: There should be no need to cast the return value to `Frames` since `List<Frames>` is strongly typed...

Comment: What's the difference between FrameList and FramesList - typo :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are *more than one* matching elements, `Single` will throw an `InvalidOperationException`. (As you've checked there is at *least* one that matches, this is the only reason I can see that you'd get this exception.)

See the Exceptions section of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118.aspx).

Comment: Grrrrr, damn, *&%$^^, slaps face.   Thanks!!!!!  I take the XML which populates FramesList from an outside source who assures me that it is impossible to have dupes.  Guess what?

Comment: Good thing you weren't using `First`, then, or you'd have never known :)

Comment: Yep!  I just added a new exception class to my XML parser ;)

Answer (score 3):

FrameList may not have single instance that matches the seach criteria. Which casuse the exception in consequence.

As per msdn documentation for **[Enumerable.Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx)**

> Single returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception
>   if there is not exactly one element in the sequence".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of querying for a single item, you can also call FirstOrDefault. That call won't throw an exception in your face, when you depend on values from third party xml files.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm accepting Rawling's answer as earliest, correct and correctly codes out my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You should `First`, `Single` is use where you expect only a single element to be returned.

```
frames = (Frames)FramesList.First(r => r.ExerciseID.Equals(exerciseID));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm accepting Rawling's answer as earliest, correct and correctly codes out my assumption.